# Simulating hdd for docker image

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker

I'm using postgres:11-alpine, and I want to reduce it's disk io speed. It look's my ssd is too fast to reproduce the problem I am getting on the production server

Any solutions?

Comment: A Docker container uses the host's kernel and hardware; it doesn't have a "hard disk" to speak of.  You need a virtual machine setup if you do need to simulate the hardware.

Comment: You likely would need to simulate the difference between random and sequential as well, which sounds hard and fraught.  Maybe rent a box on AWS or some other provider with hdd-class storage?  That is what I've done when I can't find a local box with the right set up.

Answer (score 2):

Simply start the container with the `--device-read-iops` and `--device-write-iops` options to limit the number of I/O operations per second.

For example: `--device-write-iops=/dev/sda:1000`

Comment: Is there any way to do it with docker compose v3? It seems blkio options were removed since v2x

Comment: Looks like they were removed to support `swarm` better. See https://superuser.com/questions/1306172/limit-usage-of-disk-i-o-by-docker-container-using-compose/1725028#1725028